# Jquery: Get value of more than one <select> drop-down

Tags: php, jquery

I am fetching user record from db-table like

```
<?php $row=1; ?>
<select id="status<?php echo $row; ?>" name="status<?php echo $row; ?>">
    <option value="0">Active</option>
    <option value="1">Block</option>
</select>
<?php $row++; ?>

----------------------------------------
  Name                    Status
----------------------------------------
  Abc                     Active
  Def                     Block
  Ghi                     Active
  Jkl                     Block
----------------------------------------
```

where status is  drop-down with two status for each user and If I want to change the status of any user then I select an option from that  drop-down and at the same time the status must update in db-table.
For this I coded:

```
for(var r=1; r<=4; r++){
    $("status").each(function() {
        var sld = $("#status").val();
        alert(sld);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "response.php",
            data: "sld="+sld,
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg); // this is the response
            }
        });
    });
}
```

but for loop does not create script for each  drop-down....

Comment: Okay looks like you've gone wrong. First of all "status" in line 2 looks like it needs to be ".status" and each drop down needs the class of status. ID of status won't work because you can only have one

Comment: Your PHP code is irrelevant to the question. You should include the HTML that PHP emits, as this is what the browser and JavaScript/jQuery are looking at. _(Hint: View Source, or Inspect Element)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to remove that for loop, and use this code.
My event is now "change" and it will submit two variables, "id" and "sld". You then update your php script to check $_POST['id'] and $_POST['sld'] and then update these into the database.

add class="status" to each of the drop downs.

```
$(".status").change(function() {
        var sld = $(this).val();
        alert(sld);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "response.php",
            data: { "sld": sld, "id":$(this).attr('id').replace('status','') },
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg); // this is the response
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('status')` would select elements that have the node name of `status`. Do you have that? Or did you mean `$('.status')`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having more than one element with the same ID which will be an invalid HTML.

Put a class for your select boxes and then you can use something like this.

```
$("select.status").each(function() {
    var sld = this.value;
    alert(sld);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "response.php",
        data: "sld="+sld,
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg); // this is the response
        }
    });
});
```

Also I don't find any use of the for loop in the example.